# Iterative polynomial multiplication -- Chebyshev polynomials in Python

Tags: python, iteration, polynomial-math

My question is: What is the best approach to iterative polynomial multiplication in Python?

I thought an interesting project would be to write a function in Python to generate the coefficients and exponents of each term for a Chebyshev polynomial of a given degree. The recursive function to generate such a polynomial (represented by T<sub>n</sub>(x)) is:

```
With:
```

T<sub>0</sub>(x) = 1

```
and
```

T<sub>1</sub>(x) = x:

T<sub>n</sub>(x) = 2xT<sub>n-1</sub>(x) - T<sub>n-2</sub>(x)

What I have so far isn't very useful, but I am having trouble kind of wrapping my brain around how to get this going. What I want to happen is the following:

```
>> chebyshev(4)
[[8,4], [8,2], [1,0]]
```

This list represents the Chebyshev polynomial of the 4th degree:
    T<sub>4</sub>(x) = 8x<sup>4</sup> - 8x<sup>2</sup> + 1

```
import sys
def chebyshev(n, a=[1,0], b=[1,1]):
    z = [2,1]
    result = []
    if n == 0:
        return a
    if n == 1:
        return b
    print >> sys.stderr, ([z[0]*b[0], 
                           z[1]+b[1]],
                          a) # This displays the proper result for n = 2
    return result
```

The [one solution](http://wj32.wordpress.com/2008/03/07/more-polynomial-related-functions/) I found on the web didn't work, so I am hoping someone can shed some light.

p.s. More information on Chebyshev polynomials: [CSU Fullteron](http://math.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/chebyshevpolymod.html), [Wikipedia - Chebyshev polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials). They are very cool/useful, and tie together some really interesting trig functions/properties; worth a read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SciPy has an implementation for Chebyshev

http://www.scipy.org/doc/api_docs/SciPy.special.orthogonal.html

I would suggest looking at their code.

Comment: Thank you much! I had looked for it in numpy, but not SciPy.

Answer (score 0):

The best implementation for Chebyshev is :

```
// Computes T_n(x), with -1 <= x <= 1
real T( int n, real x )
{
  return cos( n*acos(x) ) ;
}
```

If you test this against other implementations, including explicit polynomial evaluation and [iteratively computing the recurrence relation](http://www.storage-b.com/math-numerical-analysis/27), this is actually just as fast.  [Try it yourself.](http://jsperf.com/chebyshev-polynomial-evaluation).

Generally:

- Explicit polynomial evaluation is the worst (for large n)
- Recursive evaluation is a little better
- cosine evaluation is the best

Comment: The cosine evaluation can beat recurrence relations, but only for _very_ large `n`. (cos and arccos are expensive to compute.) Besides, one often needs the values of all polynomials up to a certain degree, which is exceptionally cheap with recurrence of course.

Answer (score 0):

[orthopy](https://github.com/nschloe/orthopy#line-segment--1-1-with-weight-function-1-x%CE%B1-1x%CE%B2) (a project of mine) also supports computation of Chebyshev polynomials. With

```
import orthopy

# from sympy.abc import x
x = 0.5

normalization = "normal"   # or "classical", "monic"
evaluator = orthopy.c1.chebyshev1.Eval(x, normalization)
for _ in range(10):
    print(next(evaluator))
```

```
0.5641895835477564
0.39894228040143276
-0.39894228040143265
...
```

you get the values of the polynomials with increasing degree at `x = 0.5`. You can use a list/vector of multiple values, or even sympy symbolics.

Computation happens with recurrence relations of course. If you're interested in the coefficients, check out

```py
rc = orthopy.c1.chebyshev1.RecurrenceCoefficients("monic", symbolic=True)
```